# Allow people to filter in a shared read-only excel file on Sharepoint

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint

I have an excel file that is hosted on Sharepoint and accessible to anyone with a link.
I don't want anyone to be able to change the data in the file, so I've removed Edit access for everyone but me.

The tricky thing is that I do want people to be able to filter in the table (e.g. the first column lists the state where this list of companies is located - I want people to be able to select a state from the filter dropdown menu and only see rows matching that state).
I don't want these filters to affect how others view the file, though, so every user that clicks on the link to the file should see the unfiltered table then be able to filter it themselves.

Right now, it seems as though this is impossible without the user saving a copy of their file first.

Are there any workarounds or other possible services (besides Sharepoint) that would have this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think this requirement is feasible.

Whether you use SharePoint or other services, the end result is that the user's permissions are restricted: ***They don't have permission to modify.***

The only possibility is that Excel has separate permission settings for filter.

But as far as I know, Excel doesn't have this setting.

I suggest you create this workbook (which need to filter the view) as a new separate Excel file and give the permission to modify it.